# Meta boxes not saving

Tags: posts, metabox, customization

I have a custom post with two custom meta boxes that I add using this tutorial:http://wptheming.com/2010/08/custom-metabox-for-post-type/

When I update the post, it disappears. My code:

```
function my_create_post_types() {


// Set UI labels for Custom Post Type
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Startups', 'Post Type General Name', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Startup', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Startups', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Padre Startup', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'Todas las Startups', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'Ver Startup', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Añadir nueva Startup', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Añadir nueva', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Editar Startup', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Actualizar Startup', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Buscar Startup', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'No encontrado', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'No encontrado', 'twentythirteen' ),
    );


// Set other options for Custom Post Type

    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'Startups', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Startup news and reviews', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        // Features this CPT supports in Post Editor
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes' ,'post-formats','tags'),
        // You can associate this CPT with a taxonomy or custom taxonomy. 
        'taxonomies'          => array('post_tag'),
        /* A hierarchical CPT is like Pages and can have
        * Parent and child items. A non-hierarchical CPT
        * is like Posts.
        */  
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'register_meta_box_cb' => 'add_url_metaboxes',
        'menu_icon'           => 'http://cink-innovation.es/hub/wp-content/themes/hub/images/startups.png',
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
    );

                        $img_src = $retina === 'true' ? aq_resize( get_post_meta( $post_id, 'krown_post_image', true ), '1340', null ) : aq_resize( get_post_meta( $post_id, 'krown_post_image', true ), '680', null );


// Registering your Custom Post Type
    register_post_type( 'Startups', $args);


// Set UI labels for Custom Post Type
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Mentores', 'Post Type General Name', 'shadow' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Mentores', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'shadow' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Mentores', 'shadow' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Padre Mentores', 'shadow' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'Todas los Mentores', 'shadow' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'Ver Mentores', 'shadow' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Añadir nuevo Mentor', 'shadow' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Añadir nuevo', 'shadow' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Editar Mentor', 'shadow' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Actualizar Mentor', 'shadow' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Buscar Mentor', 'shadow' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'No encontrado', 'shadow' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'No encontrado', 'shadow' ),
    );

// Set other options for Custom Post Type

    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'Mentores', 'shadow' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Mentores news and reviews', 'shadow' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        // Features this CPT supports in Post Editor
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes' ,'post-formats','tags'),
        // You can associate this CPT with a taxonomy or custom taxonomy. 
        'taxonomies'          => array('post_tag'),
        /* A hierarchical CPT is like Pages and can have
        * Parent and child items. A non-hierarchical CPT
        * is like Posts.
        */  
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 6,
        'menu_icon'           => 'http://cink-innovation.es/hub/wp-content/themes/hub/images/mentores.png',
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',

    );

                        $img_src = $retina === 'true' ? aq_resize( get_post_meta( $post_id, 'krown_post_image', true ), '1340', null ) : aq_resize( get_post_meta( $post_id, 'krown_post_image', true ), '680', null );

    // Registering your Custom Post Type
    register_post_type( 'Mentores', $args); 



}


/* Hook into the 'init' action so that the function
* Containing our post type registration is not 
* unnecessarily executed. 
*/

add_action( 'init', 'my_create_post_types' );


/*.........................CUSTOM FIELDS...................................*/


function add_url_metaboxes() {
    add_meta_box('wpt_url_boxes', 'Información Adicional', 'wpt_url_boxes', 'startups', 'normal', 'high');
    }

// Metaboxes

function wpt_url_boxes() {
    global $post;


    // Noncename needed to verify where the data originated
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="urlmeta_noncename" id="urltmeta_noncename" value="' . 
    wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';

    // Get the location data if its already been entered
    $web = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_web', true);
        $face = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_face', true);

    // Echo out the field
        echo '<p>Url de la Startup:</p>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="_web" value="' . $web  . '" class="wideurl" />';
        echo '<p>Dirección de Facebook:</p>';
        echo '<input type="text" name="_face" value="' . $face  . '" class="wideface" />';

}

// Save the Metabox Data

function wpt_save_url_meta($post_id, $post) {



    // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
    // because save_post can be triggered at other times
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['urlmeta_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
    return $post->ID;
    }

    // Is the user allowed to edit the post or page?

    if ( 'Startups' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
} else {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return;
}
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;

    // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
    // We'll put it into an array to make it easier to loop though.

    $url_meta['_web'] = $_POST['_web'];
    $url_meta['_face'] = $_POST['_face'];

    // Add values of $events_meta as custom fields

    foreach ($url_meta as $key => $value) { // Cycle through the $events_meta array!
        if( $post->post_type == 'startups' ) return; // Don't store custom data twice
        $value = implode(',', (array)$value); // If $value is an array, make it a CSV (unlikely)
        if(get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, FALSE)) { // If the custom field already has a value
            update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
        } else { // If the custom field doesn't have a value
            add_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
        }
        if(!$value) delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key); // Delete if blank
    }

}

add_action('save_post', 'wpt_save_url_meta', 1, 2); // save the custom fields
```

Any idea? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is this line:

```
     if( $post->post_type == 'startups' ) return;
```

Won't your custom posts always have the type `startups`?  Basically you are telling your code that whenever I save my custom post type, ignore my custom fields.  You probably meant to have one of the WP reserved types (e.g. `revision` or `attachment`) that would prevent your meta data from being overwritten in inconvenient ways.

I would change that line to

```
     if( $post->post_type == 'revision' ) return;
```

Or you could remove that line entirely (for testing purposes).